# ls --color=auto is not working?

Tags: customization, ls

Why `ls` command is not showing color in Ubuntu 14.04.2? Previously it worked.

My alias report:

```sh
alias cp='cp -i'
alias gdb='gdb -q'
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
#alias dir='dir --color=auto'
#alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
```

Comment: please add output of `grep alias ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Your alias is "ll" not "ls" , use alias ls='ls --color=auto'

Comment: @DavidFoerster - OK, done

Comment: or type ll instead of ls....

Answer (score 1):

Your alias is "`ll`" not "`ls`", use:

```sh
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```